# How to get the row of a item in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
list = [
    ['a'],
    ['b'],
    ['c']
]
```

If I'd want to remove b, I would do it like this:

```
list.pop(1)
```

But what if I don't know in witch row the b is?
And so first I want to find the row of b and save it as a variable to use it like this:

```
list.pop(variable)
```

I tried

```
index = list.index('b')
```

but i didn't worked.

Comment: `b` isn't in the list, `['b']` is

Comment: because `'b'` isnt in the list, `['b']` is in the list.

Comment: Also, you could just use `.remove`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`remove` does the whole job, both finds and removes the value. You just need to look for the *whole* value, i.e., not just `'b'` but `['b']`.

```
lst.remove(['b'])
```

And don't call your list `list`, as you then can't access the normal `list` anymore (at least not the usual way).

Answer (score 1):

`.remove()` will delete the first occurrence of `['b']` in the list :

```
lst.remove(['b'])
```

to remove all of them :

```
print([i for i in lst if i != ['b']])
```

Second one actually creates a new list instead of mutating the original list.